# Ping from VMware guest machine to the Ethernet interface of the Host machine

Tags: ip, ping, vmware-player, icmp

I want to ping from a VMware player guest machine to the Ethernet Interface of the host machine.

The VMware guest machine has an adress in the VMWare Virtual Network:`192.168.221.4` so I am able to ping to the VMware virtual Network adress of the Host `192.168.221.1`, but not to the Ethernet interface adress of the Host `169.254.203.46` any solutions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two addresses are on differing network segments, so messages cannot cross over.

You can specify for the virtual machine the Network Adapter as NAT or Bridged
so it participates in the same network segment as the host.

Otherwise, you will need to use the
[route command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Route_%28command%29)
to add a static route from one segment to the other.
There are many articles to be found on the subject, for example
[How to Add a Static TCP/IP Route to the Windows Routing Table](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/adding-a-tcpip-route-to-the-windows-routing-table/).